# Why does fabletools::model() throw an error with this synthetic data?

Tags: r, fable-r, tsibble

[2019-01-02 Update]

Removed `tsibble` development and installed `tsibble_0.8.5` from CRAN.

Session Info

```
R version 3.6.2 (2019-12-12)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 19.10
tsibble_0.8.5    fable_0.1.1      fabletools_0.1.1
```

`fit` now shows `<S3: lst_mdl>` from the cell output.

At R console,

```
> fit
# A mable: 1 x 1
ets         
<model>     
1 <ETS(A,A,N)>
```

It looks likes an untrained model.

---

[Original]

On learning to fit time-series models with synthetic data, I used code based on [intro to fable](https://fable.tidyverts.org/articles/fable.html), and [create a tsibble](https://tsibble.tidyverts.org/reference/tsibble.html) to make this example code:

```
library(fable)
library(tsibble)

fit <- tsibble(
  date = as.Date("2017-01-01") + 0:9,
  value = rnorm(10),
  index = date
) %>% 
  model(ets = ETS(value ~ trend("A")))
fit
```

The above code shows error

```
1 error encountered for ets
[1] No common type for `..1` <interval> and `..2` <double>.
```

Searching ["No common type"](https://github.com/tidyverts/fabletools/search?q=No%20common%20type&unscoped_q=No%20common%20type) in fabletools suggests to me the message, and the error, comes from another package. A google search suggested it was tidyr, but it looks like this [pull request](https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyr/issues/663) changed it.

`traceback()` showed an unrelated error that originated from earlier in the session.

What can one do to further investigate this error?

What can I do to get the model to fit to the data?

Comment: Please check your versions.  I don't get an error with `fable` `0.1.1` and `tsibble` `0.8.2` on `R 3.6.2`

Comment: Looks like you're using `tsibble` dev version, which isn't currently compatible with `fable`.  Installing tsibble from CRAN should solve the problem.